# symfony: credentials for an action in the backend

Tags: symfony1, credentials, backend

I have this in the generator.yml of a module:

```
config:
  actions:
    _new:  { credentials: [user] }
```

and I've overwriten the action "new" i mention in the generator.yml
this way:

```
public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
{

var_dump($this->getCredential());

$this->form = $this->configuration->getForm();
$this->Sedi = $this->form->getObject();
}
```

When i execute the new action i get "null". I expected to get "user".

I did "cc".

Any idea?

Javier

Comment: The 'credentials' option for a generator action specifies which credentials are sufficient to execute that action. It does NOT provide the executor with the specified credentials. Are you sure you already have the "user" credentials?

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I'm logged in with a user that has the credential "admin" (in the action new i have checked it using var_dump($this->getUser()->getCredentials());) but i can execute the action new... I expected not to be able to execute it... I did "cc".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `security.yml` to restrict actions.